# A power of two doesn't have any other odd divisor than $\pm 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm struggling to prove that any power of two, for instance, $2^3=8$, only has $\pm 1$ as the only odd divisor. In other words,

$$(n\text{ is a power of two})\iff \neg(n \text{ has other odd divisors than }\pm1)$$

$n$ is a power of two means: $\exists k\in \mathbb{N}:n=2^k$

Comment: Are you allowed to use the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), aka uniqueness of prime factorization?

Comment: Hi Brian! Yes i am

Comment: Then see kccu's answer below. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) or Unique Factorization Theorem. This says every integer greater than 1 has a unique factorization as a product of primes, up to reordering the factors. Since any power of 2 has a prime factorization involving only 2s, that is the only prime factorization. Hence if a power of 2 has an odd factor, that odd factor must be $\pm 1$ or have an odd prime factor. The latter is not possible, as this would imply the power of 2 also has an odd prime factor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Consider all prime factors of $2^n$ and think whether they are odd or even.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

If a number is a power of $2$, it will only have $2$ as its factor. Odd numbers by definition do not have $2$ as a factor. If there are no common factors, they wont be divisible.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Sam!